# How to reactivate Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that interacts with facebook API, but somehow my adm account from business was disabled after some security checks from Facebook.

Ok, all I have to do is reactivate my root/adm account.
Here the problem begins.

When trying to login to my root/business account, I have to make a few steps to reactivate, OK.

But on first step, that is "Add a phone number" to my account.
When clicking in the button to add that number, the error message shows up: "Please Login Again. Your current session has expired. Please login again to continue.".

And no matter how many times I login again, this message ALWAYS shows, making me unable to reactivate account to regain communication with Facebook API.

Prints:

[image]

[image]

PS: I've already clicked on "I'm having trouble with this step", but there isn't anything helpfull.

Does anyone has any tip for me? Or know a way to contact directly Facebook Development Team?

Any ideas would welcome at all.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an actual programming question.

Comment: Are you talking about an actual business manager user - or what do you mean by “business account”?

Comment: @CBroe business account means the account you use to login into https://business.facebook.com/, as that one is my app root account.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask your question directly in the business user community where you can get help from Facebook Admins. Anyway, there is no direct contact to the Facebook Development Team.

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/